# Join two query result based on st_contain geom

Tags: postgis

I have two different polygon layers. I need to get polygon that contains a similar provided point. Currently I am doing 2 different query to get the result. The queries are as follows

Query 1:

```
SELECT t1.column1, t1.column2, t1.column3, t1.column4
FROM table1 t1
WHERE ST_Contains(geom, ST_GeometryFromText('POINT($longitude $latitude)'))
```

Query 2:

```
SELECT t2.column1, t2.column2, t2.column3
FROM table2 t2
WHERE ST_Contains(geom, ST_GeometryFromText('POINT($longitude $latitude)'))
```

Can I get all the result (`t1.column1, t1.column2, t1.column3, t1.column4, t2.column1, t2.column2, t2.column3`) in a single query? Then what join I need to apply?

Comment: I assume the table1 in query 2 should really be table2, ie, table1 and table2 are different? You can't usually merge columns like this unless they share some common field, ie, you are doing a join or a crosstab. Does the geom column in table1 and table2 have the same values?

Comment: I don't think you can do this unless there is something common between the two tables to join on. You haven't made it clear if there is any common column. You can do a spatial join, of course, but it isn't clear from the question that is what you are looking for.

Comment: You can make a Descartes product of the two tables and apply two st_contains in the where with an and between them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should join the rows of the two tables to have columns from both tables. As there is no useful join condition between the tables I would do a Descartes product and select from joined rows in the where clause:

```
SELECT t1.column1, t1.column2, t1.column3, t1.column4, t2.column1, t2.column2, t2.column3
FROM table1 t1, table2 t2
WHERE ST_Contains(t1.geom, ST_GeometryFromText('POINT($longitude $latitude)')) and 
            ST_Contains(t2.geom, ST_GeometryFromText('POINT($longitude $latitude)'));
```

It can be very slow for huge tables.

Another approach can be to intersect the two tables with polygons and select with st_contains.